# Binding selectedItems of MultiComboBox to OData navigation property

Tags: odata, sapui5

I would like to display MultiComboBox with preselected items.

As an example let's say I have three entities in my OData service:

- Car (CarId, Name)
- CarColors (CarId, ColorId)
- AvailableCarColors (ColorId, Description)

A car can be painted using any number of available colors. Imagine a car configurator which enables you to choose colors for your car.

I would like to display MultiComboBox with items bound to `AvailableCarColors` and use `CarColors` as source of selected items.

Is it possible to perform such binding without contorller logic, only using xml view?

[Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/GjERr6lkY9LCtX4a4m4R)

In the example above I would like to have:

- Porsche initially assigned Blue, Cyan and Magenta
- Mercedes initially assigned Red
- BMW initially assigned Green, Yellow, Black

Also, example utilizes JSONModel and I am trying to do the same with ODataModel.

Comment: you're not using the sap configurator for this? i do a lot of work in the sap automotive space and making one of those in fiori properly is a ton of work. the number of options explodes quite quickly

Comment: hi, what I provided was just an abstract example to better explain what I am trying to do

Answer (score 1):

If you have a navigation property from Car to CarColors then it's possible, however not completely without a code. At the point where you react to the change of CarId you have to make a context binding, any control can be bound to a context.

For example, suppose you have navigation property CarColors of entity Car, and also it is assumed that you use unnamed OData model, then you can bind the context in this way (for a View):

```
this.getView().bindObject({
    path: oDataModel.createKey("/Car", { CarId: <some car id> }),
    parameters: {
        expand: "CarColors"
    }
});
```

After that you can bind your MultiComboBox items in this form:

```
items="{CarColors}"
```

Note, there is no starting slash in the binding as it should take the property from the context.

If you want to show ALL colors with some of them selected then it can be done with complex binding and formatter function.

So, the MultiComboBox **items** should be bound to AvailableCarColors and **selectedKeys** should have complex binding, something like this:

```
selectedKeys="{
    path: 'CarColors', formatter: '.formaSelectedColors'
}
```

formaSelectedColors has single array parameter with CarColors and must return String array with all color keys.

Comment: Am I mistaken, or would I just receive a MultiComboBox with only those items that are in navigation property? I would like the MultiComboBox to have ALL AvailableCarColors and only CarColors selected

Comment: You are right, and I misunderstood the task. Not possible without additional coding. However, it is possible with complex binding and formatter function.

Answer (score 1):

I have modified your JSON for correct binding, added new property called `KeysSelected` for selecting the colors corresponding to the car. As per the binding is concern the object related to the individual car should be inside.

Used `selectedKeys` property for selecting the key(colors)

`<MultiComboBox ..... selectedKeys="{KeysSelected}" >`

**Working code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>SAPUI5 single file template</title>
        <script src="https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
            id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
            data-sap-ui-theme="sap_belize"
            data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"
            data-sap-ui-bindingSyntax="complex"
            data-sap-ui-compatVersion="edge"
            data-sap-ui-preload="async"></script>

        <script id="myXmlView" type="ui5/xmlview">

            <mvc:View
                controllerName="MyController"
                xmlns="sap.m"
                xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
                xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
                xmlns:f="sap.ui.layout.form">

                <Shell> 
                    <List items="{/Cars}">
                        <CustomListItem>
                            <f:SimpleForm layout="ResponsiveGridLayout" editable="true">
                                <Label text="{Name}" />
                                <MultiComboBox items="{/AvailableCarColors}" selectedKeys="{KeysSelected}" >
                                    <core:Item key="{ColorId}" text="{Description}"/>
                                </MultiComboBox>   
                            </f:SimpleForm>
                        </CustomListItem>
                    </List>                    
                </Shell>
            </mvc:View>
        </script>


        <script>
            sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(function () {
                "use strict";

                sap.ui.define([
                    "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
                    "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel"
                ], function (Controller, JSONModel) {
                    "use strict";

                    return Controller.extend("MyController", {
                        onInit : function () {
                            var oModel = new JSONModel({
                                Cars: [
                                    { 
                                        CarId: 1,
                                        KeysSelected : ["3", "4", "5"],
                                        Name: "Porsche",
                                        ToColors:[
                                            { CarId: 1, ColorId: 3}, 
                                            { CarId: 1, ColorId: 4}, 
                                            { CarId: 1, ColorId: 5},                                            
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    { 
                                        CarId: 2,
                                        KeysSelected : ["1"],
                                        Name: "Mercedes",
                                        ToColors:[
                                            { CarId: 2, ColorId: 1},                                        
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    { 
                                        CarId: 3,
                                        KeysSelected : ["2", "6", "7"],
                                        Name: "BMW",
                                        ToColors:[
                                            { CarId: 3, ColorId: 2},
                                            { CarId: 3, ColorId: 6},
                                            { CarId: 3, ColorId: 7},                                       
                                        ]
                                    },                                    
                                ],
                                AvailableCarColors: [
                                    { ColorId: 1, Description: 'Red' , KeysSelected : ["0", "1"]},
                                    { ColorId: 2, Description: 'Green' },
                                    { ColorId: 3, Description: 'Blue' },
                                    { ColorId: 4, Description: 'Cyan' },
                                    { ColorId: 5, Description: 'Magenta' },
                                    { ColorId: 6, Description: 'Yellow' },
                                    { ColorId: 7, Description: 'Black' },

                                ],
                                CarColors: [
                                    { CarId: 1, ColorId: 3}, 
                                    { CarId: 1, ColorId: 4}, 
                                    { CarId: 1, ColorId: 5},
                                    { CarId: 2, ColorId: 1},
                                    { CarId: 3, ColorId: 2},
                                    { CarId: 3, ColorId: 6},
                                    { CarId: 3, ColorId: 7},   
                                ]
                            });
                            this.getView().setModel(oModel);
                        }
                    });
                });
                sap.ui.xmlview({
                    viewContent : jQuery("#myXmlView").html()
                }).placeAt("content");
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body class="sapUiBody">
        <div id="content"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use expression binding, its work for one selection

```
<MultiComboBox items="{/AvailableCarColors}" selectedKeys="{=${Name} === 'Porsche' ? '3': ${Name} === 'BMW' ? '2' : '1' }" >
```

But Iam not sure how to use for multi selection '3,4,5' and '2,6,7' dosent work may be i18n solve.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the answer.

I would like for it to work dynamically, so that my changes to selected items would be reflected in bound entityset.

Thinking about it now I don't think it is really possible to be done easily as I would need to keep track of entity creation / deletion every time someone changes selected items.